# infowindow related to marker google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, marker, infowindow

I have created code to show the cluster marker using google map V3. The problem is in the `infowindow` for each marker. I think the bug is that in every iteration of the loop, the reinitialize the content of the other marker and just save the last inserted.

Here is my attempt...

http://www.ermes.net/user/loadscrolling/load_first.php

Thanks for help!

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

 function initialize() {
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, 9.1419);

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 2,
          center: center,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        var tweets = <?php echo json_encode($mapLocations); ?>;
        var markers = [];

<? for ($j=0; $j<count($resultArrayAd); $j++) { ?>
    var i=<?=$j++?>;
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(<?=$resultArrayAd[$j]['Lat']?>),parseFloat(<?=$resultArrayAd[$j]['Lng']?>));

    <?  
    $userList2 = new user_account($resultArrayAd[$j]["user_id"]); 
    $user_avatar2=$userList2->get_avatar(); 
    $path2 =enleveaccents($user_avatar2->get_document_filename());
    $user_nick=enleveaccents($resultArrayAd[$j]["user_name"]);
    $user_id=$resultArrayAd[$j]['user_id'];
    $usr_details = new user_details($user_id);
    if (strlen($path2) > 0)  {
    $path_img= "/images/thumb_".$path2;
    } else {
    $path_img = "/img/avatar_profilo.jpg";
        } 
?>

    var contentString = '<table><tr><td width="350">'+
    '<a href="/user/<?=$user_id?>/<?=$user_nick?>.html" target="_top">'+
    '<img align=left width=100 height=65 border=0 src="<?=$path_img?>" hspace=4 vspace=2>'+
    '<font size=1 face=verdana><b><?=$user_nick?></b></font></a><br/>'+
    '<span style="color:#555555;font-size:12px;line-hieght:13px;">'+
    '<b>Indirizzo:</b><br/>' +
    '<b>Tel:</b> <br/>'+
    '</span>'+
    '<div class="clearBoth"></div></td></tr></table>'+
    '<div class="clearBoth"></div>';


var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        icon:"<?=$resultArrayAd[$j]['user_icon']?>",
        title:"<?=$user_nick?>",
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
markers.push(marker);

<? } ?> 

        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this bug ;-)
and here is a correct code..

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function initialize() {
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(9.4419, 9.1419);

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 2,
          center: center,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var markers = [];
        // create the infowindow out of the for boucle
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

<? for ($j=0; $j<count($resultArrayAd); $j++) { ?>

var i=<?=$j++?>;
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(<?=$resultArrayAd[$j]['Lat']?>),parseFloat(<?=$resultArrayAd[$j]['Lng']?>));   
    <?  
    $userList2 = new user_account($resultArrayAd[$j]["user_id"]); 
    $user_avatar2=$userList2->get_avatar(); 
    $path2 =enleveaccents($user_avatar2->get_document_filename());
    $user_nick=enleveaccents($resultArrayAd[$j]["user_name"]);
    $user_id=$resultArrayAd[$j]['user_id'];
    $usr_details = new user_details($user_id);
    if (strlen($path2) > 0)  {
    $path_img= "/images/thumb_".$path2;
    } else {
    $path_img = "/img/avatar_profilo.jpg";
        } 
?>
 var html = '<table><tr><td width="200">'+
    '<a href="/user/<?=$user_id?>/<?=$user_nick?>.html" target="_top">'+
    '<img align=left width=80 height=65 border=0 src="<?=$path_img?>" hspace=4 vspace=2>'+
    '<font size=1 face=verdana><b><?=$user_nick?></b></font></a><br/>'+
    '<span style="color:#555555;font-size:12px;line-hieght:13px;">'+
    '<b>Indirizzo:</b> <?=enleveaccents($usr_details->user_address);?><br/>' +
    '<b>Tel:</b> <?=enleveaccents($usr_details->user_phone);?><br/>'+
    '</span>'+
    '<div class="clearBoth"></div></td></tr></table>'+
    '<div class="clearBoth"></div>';

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        icon:"<?=$resultArrayAd[$j]['user_icon']?>",
        title:"<?=$user_nick?>",
    });
// call to the function....
bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
markers.push(marker);
<? } ?> 

// create a function bindInfoWindow

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
}

        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```